# AngleSharp, select submit input on SubmitAsync

Tags: c#, parsing, input, submit, anglesharp

I have a question
As with SubmitAsync, select input (type submit) because there are several such inputs on the page and the script presses (executes) the first input

```
var document = _context.Active; 
var form = document.QuerySelector(formSelector) as IHtmlFormElement; 
var button = document.QuerySelector(buttonSelector) as IHtmlFormElement; 
if (form != null){form.SetValues(fields); } 
await form.SubmitAsync(button);
```

[submit inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQq0f.png)
I wanted to specify the input via the function overload, but as it understood it simply points to the input that is in the form

Thanks!

Comment: Decided, I use: await document.QuerySelector<IHtmlInputElement>(buttonSelector).SubmitAsync(fields);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a form in AngleSharp there exist various helpers. According to the specification it can make a difference which input field / button was used to submit a form. Therefore a W3C compliant browser engine will do the following when submitting a form

- submit the name of the button / input that was used (if a button / input with a valid name was used)
- submit the mouse coordinates if an type=image field was used
- some other more exotic stuff

Now that we discussed this we know already why a simple `form.SubmitAsync()` won't be that helpful - in case we want / have to "fake" submitting the form by clicking somewhere. Fortunately, however, AngleSharp has another overload on the form that specifies a "source" (of the submission). This source can be any `IHtmlElement`.

In your code above you are providing null as source (see `document.QuerySelector(buttonSelector) as IHtmlFormElement` - I suppose the query selector should actually yield a button - either a `IHtmlButtonElement` or `IHtmlInputElement` - in any case an `IHtmlElement`, but not an `IHtmlFormElement` -- this is not an "element of the form" but "the form element").

Therefore the following line

```
document.QuerySelector<IHtmlInputElement>(buttonSelector).Su‌​bmitAsync(fields)
```

is the same as

```
var form = document.QuerySelector<IHtmlFormElement>(formSelector);

if (form != null)
{
    form.SetValues(fields);
    form.SubmitAsync(document.QuerySelector(buttonSelector)); 
}
```

Hope this helps!